# How do I keep old 1 pane glas from blowing out by high wind?

Tags: windows

Renting in old house with a couple of old 1 pane glass windows which need to be secure for hurricanes.  I am a senior female and need an easy reassuring fix.  The owner doesn't care, so I must do it myself.  Do you have any ideas on how to secure the windows?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, so I'll put it here in the comment:  Unless it's specifically in your rental contract, don't do anything.  It's the property owner's responsibility to protect his or her property from hurricanes (at least to have hurricane panels ready for install).  If a hurricane is coming your way, leave the property until it has passed.  If the home is not in livable condition when you return, then find another place to rent.

Comment: Adding on to @Edwin's comment, make sure you have renter's insurance. It is very cheap, and would protect all of your personal property in such a situation.

Answer (score 1):

It takes an insane amount of wind to blow out glass. I've been through a couple dozen hurricanes, and haven't seen winds high enough to blow glass out.

Debris in the wind, however, will. Only real protection from flying debris is plywood on the outside, and some powerful prayer.

If you aren't capable of covering the windows in plywood, nail heavy blankets tightly over the inside of the window, right on the trim. It won't prevent glass breakage, but should slow down any debris that makes it through.

I strongly urge you, if you are senior and alone, to seek public shelter, or stay at church, or with friends. Let people too young and ignorant to know better ride the storms.

Let me tell you a quick story. Hurricane Isabel - I sent my family inland to be protected from the storm surge, I stayed at the house to make sure everything was okay. As the storm surge waters rose, I watched the waters lap up to the house. I decided to grab the hatchet, and thought if the water got too high I would go up in the attic, chop a hole in the roof, and sit up on the roof during the floods. As the waters rose up another foot, and my house was completely surrounded in flood waters, I thought, " What, are you stupid?! Get the heck outta here, you can't hold back the river!!" Jumped in the truck, hauled tail outta there. Barely made it. My house was destroyed, and I probably would not have survived.

Lesson: You can't hold back the storm. Get out.